# HTTP Live Streaming using Apple mediastreamsegmenter

Tags: encoding, streaming, video-streaming, mediastreamsegmenter

I would like to implement HTTP live streaming for iPhone/iPad. I am following the apple standards and tools for same.

As of now my video source is one giving me live video from rtsp://123.123.123.123:554/mpeg4 (sample IP). but as HTTP live streaming and mediastreamsegmenter required to pass source over UDP network so i have twisted way bit.

So that i have used VLC player and first stream RTSP to UDP.

For example, i have stream video source from rtsp://123.123.123.554/mpeg4 and redirected it to 
udp://@123.123.123.17:1234 (sample ip). i have tested this with two instance of VLC on same machine to check whether live streaming is played or not. it is working fine on VLC.

now I am user MAC OS 10.6.x (Snow leopard). and use latest tools (downloaded from Apple) fro HTTP Live Streaming

I am executing the following command from terminal

```
mediastreamsegmenter -b http://demo.dummy.com/stream -s 3 -D -f /Desktop/StreamParts 123.123.123.17:1234
```

here 
**http://demo.dummy.com/stream** - server
**/Desktop/StreamParts** - Local Folder for saving .ts files
**123.123.123.17:1234** - UDP url (from where live streaming is done)

But the problem is when i execute this command. it is giving me error like

***no start access unit
error in pid 44(video) -- cc value should be 9 is 10, 1 is 2, 5 is 6, etc.***

any idea? what is going wrong here? and what this error message is showing?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be that the transport is incompatible.  Apple's tools (i.e. mediastreamsegmenter) are expecting an MPEG2 transport stream over UDP, not just RTSP sent over UDP.  The problem I have, which I'm afraid will be your next question, is how to correctly generate a MPEG2 transport stream.